# REGEX parsing string by comma and equals sign

Tags: c#, arrays, regex, string, vb.net

Let's assume I have a string variable with context

```
{ Column00 = 10.02.2020, Column01 = 287, Column02 = 0, Column03 = 200000, Column04 = Оплата (287 от 10.02.2020), Column10 = 10.02.2020, Column11 = 287, Column12 = 200000, Column13 = 0, Column14 = 287~287 }
```

and I'm very interested in obtaining array of strings like this

```
{"10.02.2020", "287", "0", "200000", "Оплата (287 от 10.02.2020)", "10.02.2020", "287", "200000", "0", "287~287"}
```

Is it possible to achieve via REGEX? Help is much appreciated.

UPD
Sometimes this part `Column04 = Оплата (287 от 10.02.2020)` can be `Column04 = Оплата (287 от 10.02.2020}` or `Column04 = Оплата {287 от 10.02.2020)`.

Comment: Why Regex? Use [String.Split method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.split?view=net-5.0) or [Regex.Split method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.regularexpressions.regex.split?view=net-5.0)

Comment: I forgot to mention that sometimes this part `Column04 = Оплата (287 от 10.02.2020)` can be `Column04 = Оплата (287 от 10.02.2020}` or `Column04 = Оплата {287 от 10.02.2020)`

Answer (score 0):

Using `String.Split` method:

```
string inp = @"{ Column00 = 10.02.2020, Column01 = 287, Column02 = 0, Column03 = 200000, Column04 = Оплата (287 от 10.02.2020), Column10 = 10.02.2020, Column11 = 287, Column12 = 200000, Column13 = 0, Column14 = 287~287 }";
var result = string.Concat("{", string.Join(", ", inp.Split(new string[]{"{ ", "{", " }", "}", ", ", " = "}, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries).Where(x => !x.StartsWith("Column"))), "}");
```

Using `Regex.Split` method:

```
var result1 = String.Join("", Regex.Split(inp, @"Column\d{1,}.=."));
```